# Ember user upload excel to csv - blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, ember.js, xlsx

With ember I am currently letting the user upload files through the ember-file-upload package and trying to parse excel files with the xlsx package but I can't seem to get them to work together. I have gotten other packages to convert the file to csv, json, etc. but can't seem to get the excel file upload to convert with xlsx and I can't seem to find any other packages that work.

I am currently trying to do it this way but it always appears empty.

```
file.onloadstart = function (e) {
    alert("started reading");
}

file.onload = function (e) {
    // pre-process data
    var binary = "";
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var length = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    // call 'xlsx' to read the file
    var workbook = XLSX.read(binary, {
        type: 'binary',
        cellDates: true,
        cellStyles: true
    });
    //return oFile;
    alert(workbook.SheetNames.length);
    alert(workbook.SheetNames[0]);
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

    var desiredCell = worksheet['A1'];
    var desiredValue = (desiredCell ? desiredCell.v : undefined);
    alert(desiredValue);
};



file.readAsArrayBuffer().then(function (data) {
    alert(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(data));
    csv2geojson.csv2geojson(data, function (err, jsondata) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Currently, `file.onloadstart` never gets called and neither does `file.onload` but when I tested outside of those the `workbook.SheetNames.length` alerts the wrong length of the `workbook.SheetNames[0]` gives a bad `sheetname` and the `desiredValue` alert is blank along with alerting `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(data)` alert is blank and with length 0.